# Use custom class as Q_PROPERTY

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

I have two classes, `TestA` and `TestB`. `TestA` extends `QObject`. I have it set up with a few `Q_PROPERTY`'s like so.

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString a_string READ getString WRITE setString)
Q_PROPERTY(int a_int READ getInt WRITE setInt)
```

And, of course, I created the appropriate getters and setters. This class works just fine.

In my second class, `TestB`, I want to create a `Q_PROPERTY` that is a `TestA`, so I did this in `testb.h`.

```
Q_PROPERTY(TestA testa READ getTestA)
public:
TestA *getTestA();
private:
TestA mTestA;
```

And this in `testb.cpp`.

```
TestA *TestB::getTestA() {return &mTestA;}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error message.

```
moc_testb.cpp: In member function 'virtual int TestB::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
moc_testb.cpp:75: error: no match for 'operator=' in '*(TestA*)_v = TestB::getTestA()'
../qttest/testa.h:7: note: candidates are: TestA& TestA::operator=(const TestA&)
```

Could someone tell me what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: can you share the example? I tried it and it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error relates to the READ operation. It is causing the QT function referenced to expect testa to be an object of type TestA, which is returned by the function getTestA. However, getTestA returns a pointer to an object of type TestA instead.

I think you can resolve the issue by changing the prototype of getTestA to 
`TestA getTestA();`

and declaring it as follows:
`TestA TestB::getTestA() {return mTestA;}`

Comment: You could add to your answer that if one wants the return type to be TestA, one can also change the type of the property to the pointer type: `Q_PROPERTY(TestA* testa READ getTestA)`

Comment: With @leemes suggestion, my compile error went away. I could have sworn that I had tried that. :}